# get tablespace output

Tags: oracle

Our oracle Oracle Enterprise manager database version is 12.1.0.2. I am trying to get all the tablespace total size,used_size, free_size in my below query. The query give me an error . With this query I wanna show below
1) target name, tablespacename, total_space,free_space, used_space in GB.
2) I want column alias name without comma
Wrote file afiedt.buf

```
  1  select  * from
  2    ( select target_name,KEY_VALUE NAME
  3  ,decode(column_label,'Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)' ,total_space
  4                      ,'Tablespace Free Space (MB)',free_space,'Tablespace Us
ed Space (MB)',used_space,column_label) as column_label
  5                     ,value
  6      from sysman.mgmt$metric_current
  7    where COLUMN_LABEL IN('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)','Tablespace Used
Space (MB)','Tablespace Free Space (MB)')
  8    and target_type = 'rac_database'
  9    )
 10      PIVOT(
 11    MAX(VALUE)
 12*   FOR COLUMN_LABEL IN( 'total_space ','used_space','free_space'))
SQL> /
                    ,'Tablespace Free Space (MB)',free_space,'Tablespace Used Sp
ace (MB)',used_space,column_label) as column_label

          *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "USED_SPACE": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select  * from
      ( select target_name,KEY_VALUE NAME
    ,decode(column_label,'Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)' ,'total_space'
                        ,'Tablespace Free Space (MB)','free_space'
                        ,'Tablespace Used Space (MB)','used_space'
                        ,column_label) as column_label
                       ,value
        from sysman.mgmt$metric_current
      where COLUMN_LABEL IN('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)','Tablespace Used Space (MB)','Tablespace Free Space (MB)')
      and target_type = 'rac_database'
      )
       PIVOT(
     MAX(VALUE)
    FOR COLUMN_LABEL IN( 'total_space','used_space','free_space'))
```

Although on my database (11g), I don't see the label "Tablespace Free Space (MB)"

Note, if you want free space for tablespaces, you could use dba_free_space:

```
select tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 as mb_free 
from dba_free_space
group by tablespace_name;
```

Comment: This is Enterprise manager oem repository database. The mgmt$ view is owned by sysman

Comment: Yes, I can select from that view, only issue is that on my instance anyway (11.2) I do not have the column_label "Tablespace Free Space (MB)", but that may be available on 12c, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify even further than @tbone's answer:

```
select *
from (
  select column_label, key_value as tablespace_name, value
  from sysman.mgmt$metric_current
  where column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)',
    'Tablespace Used Space (MB)', 'Tablespace Free Space (MB)')
  and target_type = 'rac_database'
)
pivot (
  max(value)
  for column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)' as total_space,
    'Tablespace Used Space (MB)' as used_space, 'Tablespace Free Space (MB)' as free_space)
)
/
```

Which (in 11gR2) gets output like:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                TOTAL_SPACE          USED_SPACE           FREE_SPACE          
------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
SYSAUX                         1770                 1630.25                                  
SYSTEM                         730                  727.125                                  
TEMP                           2009                 0                                        
UNDOTBS1                       3469                 20.5                                     
USERS                          832.25               54.0625                                  
...
```

In this release the `mgmt$metric_current` table doesn't have an entry for free space; I can't currently check if that's been added in 12c, but you can calculate it from the other two of course.

if you want the values in GB instead of MD just divide by 1024 in the subquery, perhaps rounding to a sensible number of digits:

```
select *
from (
  select column_label, key_value as tablespace_name,
    round(to_number(value)/1024, 2) as value
  from sysman.mgmt$metric_current
  where column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)',
    'Tablespace Used Space (MB)', 'Tablespace Free Space (MB)')
  and target_type = 'rac_database'
)
pivot (
  max(value)
  for column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)' as total_space,
    'Tablespace Used Space (MB)' as used_space,
    'Tablespace Free Space (MB)' as free_space)
)
/

TABLESPACE_NAME                         TOTAL_SPACE           USED_SPACE           FREE_SPACE
------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
UNDOTBS1                                       3.39                  .02                     
TEMP                                           1.96                    0                     
SYSAUX                                         1.73                 1.59                     
USERS                                           .81                  .05                     
SYSTEM                                          .71                  .71                     
...
```

As @tbone also suggested, there are other views that would give you this information, but on my DB at least this is significantly slower:

```
select dfs.tablespace_name,
  (select round(sum(ddf.bytes)/power(1024, 3), 2) from dba_data_files ddf
    where ddf.tablespace_name = dfs.tablespace_name) as total_space,
  (select round(sum(ds.bytes)/power(1024, 3), 2) from dba_segments ds
    where ds.tablespace_name = dfs.tablespace_name) as used_space,
  round(sum(dfs.bytes)/power(1024, 3), 2) as free_space
from dba_free_space dfs
group by dfs.tablespace_name
/

TABLESPACE_NAME                         TOTAL_SPACE           USED_SPACE           FREE_SPACE
------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
SYSAUX                                         1.73                 1.59                  .13
UNDOTBS1                                       3.39                  .08                 3.31
USERS                                           .81                  .05                  .76
SYSTEM                                          .71                  .71                    0
...
```

... and from a comment about sysman owning the table you're looking at, perhaps you can't see the DBA views when you're connected to EM.

---

You can put the pivot result into an inline view or CTE if you want to do further calculations on the results, like getting the percentage of space used:

```
with cte as (
  select *
  from (
    select column_label, key_value as tablespace_name,
      to_number(value)/1024 as value
    from sysman.mgmt$metric_current
    where column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)',
      'Tablespace Used Space (MB)', 'Tablespace Free Space (MB)')
    and target_type = 'rac_database'
  )
  pivot (
    max(value)
    for column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)' as total_space,
      'Tablespace Used Space (MB)' as used_space,
      'Tablespace Free Space (MB)' as free_space)
  )
)
select tablespace_name, round(total_space, 2) as total_space,
  round(used_space, 2) as used_space, round(free_space, 2) as free_space,
  round(100 * used_space / total_space, 2) as pct_used
from cte;
```

In 11g this also lets you calculate the free space easily, from the total and used space:

```
with cte as (
  select *
  from (
    select column_label, key_value as tablespace_name,
      to_number(value)/1024 as value
    from sysman.mgmt$metric_current
    where column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)',
      'Tablespace Used Space (MB)')
    and target_type = 'rac_database'
  )
  pivot (
    max(value)
    for column_label in ('Tablespace Allocated Space (MB)' as total_space,
      'Tablespace Used Space (MB)' as used_space)
  )
)
select tablespace_name, round(total_space, 2) as total_space,
  round(used_space, 2) as used_space,
  round(total_space - used_space, 2) as free_space,
  round(100 * used_space / total_space, 2) as pct_used
from cte;

TABLESPACE_NAME                         TOTAL_SPACE           USED_SPACE           FREE_SPACE   PCT_USED
------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
UNDOTBS1                                       3.39                  .02                 3.37        .59
TEMP                                           1.96                    0                 1.96          0
SYSAUX                                         1.73                 1.59                  .14       92.1
USERS                                           .81                  .05                  .76        6.5
SYSTEM                                          .71                  .71                    0      99.61
...
```

Comment: I want them to show in gb. How i could do this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your immense help. Alex i really appreciate your valuable time you spent to respond my thread. Now how i would convert to GB?

Comment: @user3297431 - just divide the values by 1024? I've shown an example but that seems pretty straightforward...

Comment: Thanks again. How i can calculate percent_used as another column in gb?

Comment: @user3297431 - you'd need to treat the whole query as an inline view or CTE, possibly without the rounding; and then you could use the columns generated by the pivot to calculate other things, like percent-used.

Comment: This has resolved my issue. Many many thanks to Alex and May god bless you. Take care buddy.

Comment: The reason i used metric tables because i need to setup automate TS usage report from oem so that it captures all database that is under OEM agents.