# Database Size in GB with use space and free space Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

Hi all i am trying to find database size in GB with used space and free space

Query

```
select round(sum(used.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ) || 'GB' "Database Size"
, round(sum(used.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ) –
round(free.p / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) || 'GB' "Used space"
, round(free.p / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) || 'GB' "Free space"
from (select bytes
from v$datafile
union all
select bytes
from v$tempfile
union all
select bytes
from v$log) used
, (select sum(bytes) as p
from dba_free_space) free
group by free.p
/
```

error

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 48
```

upon trying still not able to rectify the error , any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message refers to the 48th character on line 2. The 'minus' character is an [en-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), not a [hyphen/minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm). You can see the difference by [dumping the characters](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5892a768296e60af8f8ad4da3f07b738).

You may have types that accidentally, or maybe copied and pasted from, say, a Word document. That can also cause problems with 'smart' quotes and sometimes even non-breaking spaces.

Retype the character and it should work.

```
select round(sum(used.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ) || 'GB' "Database Size"
, round(sum(used.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ) -
round(free.p / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) || 'GB' "Used space"
...
```

Comment: this gives the oveall DWH how to split the size break total size vs comsumed size per schema is it possible ? example stage , edw,mart...

Comment: @rakesh - not from looking at data files, but you could look `dba_segments` to get total spaced used by schema. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42257238/266304) might be helpful; first I found, there are probably many others.

Comment: i have visited the reference url you provided , unfortunately i am unable to run this query - i don't have access for this schemas i think SYSMAN.MGMT$METRIC_CURRENT ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 17

Comment: Right, that was a bad example, though one of the queries in my answer is against `dba_segments`, and that should work. I hadn't re-read the while thing. But there are many other answers and examples on the internet that show how to get data from `dba_segments` too.

Comment: i have written some queries , can you please check in the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170585/dataware-house-total-size-vs-consumed-vs-available-size-including-various-schema