# Oracle Query to find total size vs consumed vs available size including various schemas 11g

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration

I have a requirement to come up with a break down of the below

1. overall DWH SIZE
2. used space
3. free space
4. break down of space per schema (example STAGE,EDW/CORE,MART....) (point 1,2,3 must be covered)

   **4.1 - I am interested to see specifically all the schemas break down by total table size vs used size
   (tables), i have tried the below queries (1 to 5)**

upon checking various posts it's bit confusing

some suggests checking the following tables

- DATA_SIZE (to check the data files)
- TEMP_SIZE (to check the temporaryfiles)
- SYS.V_$LOG (to check the redo log files)
- V$CONTROLFILE (to check the redo log files) DBA_SEGMENTS

i have tested the below queries

**Query 1 - actual size of the database**

```
SELECT SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS GB FROM dba_data_files;
```

**RESULT - GB**

GB
900 - only example

**Query 2 - Gives the size occupied by data in this database or Database usage details**

```
SELECT SUM (bytes)/1024/1024/1024 AS GB FROM dba_segments;
```

**RESULT- GB**

GB
900 - only example

**Query 3 - overall database size in TB**

```
SELECT 
( SELECT SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024/1024/1024 DATA_SIZE FROM DBA_DATA_FILES ) +
( SELECT NVL(SUM(BYTES),0)/1024/1024/1024/1024 TEMP_SIZE FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES ) +
( SELECT SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024/1024/1024 REDO_SIZE FROM SYS.V_$LOG ) +
( SELECT SUM(BLOCK_SIZE*FILE_SIZE_BLKS)/1024/1024/1024/1024 CONTROLFILE_SIZE FROM V$CONTROLFILE) "SIZE IN TB"
FROM
DUAL
```

**RESULT- TB**

SIZE IN TB
100 - only example

**Query 4 - Database Size in TB with use space and free space Oracle DB**

```
select round(sum(used.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024/1024 ) || 'TB' "Database Size"
, round(sum(used.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024/1024 ) -
round(free.p / 1024 / 1024 / 1024/1024) || 'TB' "Used space"
, round(free.p / 1024 / 1024 / 1024/1024) || 'TB' "Free space"
from (select bytes
from v$datafile
union all
select bytes
from v$tempfile
union all
select bytes
from v$log) used
, (select sum(bytes) as p
from dba_free_space) free
group by free.p
/
```

**RESULT- TB**

Database Size Used space Free space
100           90         10

**Query 5 - QUERY TO GET SIZE OF ALL TABLES IN AN ORACLE DATABASE SCHEMA**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT
OWNER, 
OBJECT_NAME, 
OBJECT_TYPE, 
TABLE_NAME, 
--ROUND(BYTES)/1024/1024 AS MB,
ROUND(BYTES) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS GB,
--ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(ROUND(BYTES) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) OVER(),2) AS GB_PERCENT,
ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(BYTES) OVER (), 2) PERCENTAGE,
TABLESPACE_NAME, 
EXTENTS, 
INITIAL_EXTENT,
ROUND(SUM(BYTES/1024/1024/1024) OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE_NAME)) AS TOTAL_TABLE_GB
--ROUND(SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024/1024) OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE_NAME)) AS TOTAL_TABLE_GB
FROM 
(
--TABLES
SELECT OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME, 'TABLE' AS OBJECT_TYPE,
SEGMENT_NAME AS TABLE_NAME, BYTES,
TABLESPACE_NAME, EXTENTS, INITIAL_EXTENT
FROM DBA_SEGMENTS /*DBA_SEGMENTS*/
WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION')
UNION ALL
--INDEXES
SELECT I.OWNER, I.INDEX_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME, 'INDEX' AS OBJECT_TYPE,
I.TABLE_NAME, S.BYTES,
S.TABLESPACE_NAME, S.EXTENTS, S.INITIAL_EXTENT
FROM DBA_INDEXES I /*DBA_INDEXES*/
, DBA_SEGMENTS S /*DBA_SEGMENTS*/
WHERE S.SEGMENT_NAME = I.INDEX_NAME
AND S.OWNER = I.OWNER
AND S.SEGMENT_TYPE IN ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'INDEX SUBPARTITION')
--LOB SEGMENTS
UNION ALL
SELECT L.OWNER, L.COLUMN_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME, 'LOB_COLUMN' AS OBJECT_TYPE,
L.TABLE_NAME, S.BYTES,
S.TABLESPACE_NAME, S.EXTENTS, S.INITIAL_EXTENT
FROM DBA_LOBS L, /*DBA_LOBS*/
DBA_SEGMENTS S /*DBA_SEGMENTS*/
WHERE S.SEGMENT_NAME = L.SEGMENT_NAME
AND S.OWNER = L.OWNER
AND S.SEGMENT_TYPE = 'LOBSEGMENT'
--LOB INDEXES
UNION ALL
SELECT L.OWNER, L.COLUMN_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME, 'LOB_INDEX' AS OBJECT_TYPE,
L.TABLE_NAME, S.BYTES,
S.TABLESPACE_NAME, S.EXTENTS, S.INITIAL_EXTENT
FROM DBA_LOBS L, /*DBA_LOBS*/
DBA_SEGMENTS S /*DBA_SEGMENTS*/
WHERE S.SEGMENT_NAME = L.INDEX_NAME
AND S.OWNER = L.OWNER
AND S.SEGMENT_TYPE = 'LOBINDEX'
)
WHERE OWNER IN UPPER('&SCHEMA_NAME')
)
--WHERE TOTAL_TABLE_MB > 10
ORDER BY TOTAL_TABLE_GB DESC, GB DESC
/
```

**EXPECTED_RESULTS**

```
OWNER     OBJECT_TYPE TOTAL_SPACE_GB TOTAL_SPACE_USED_GB PERCENTAGE_GB 
DWH_STAGE  TABLE      400            200                  50            
DWH_EDW    TABLE      800            400                  50    
DWH_MART   TABLE      1600           800                  50
```

could you please suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

This shows space within table segments if that is what you want but I think you probably want free space by tablespace instead.

```
select t.owner,'TABLE' OBJECT_TYPE ,t.TOTAL_SPACE_GB, u.TOTAL_SPACE_USED_GB,(u.TOTAL_SPACE_USED_GB/t.TOTAL_SPACE_GB)*100 PERCENTAGE_USED
from
(select owner,sum(bytes)/(1024*1024*1024) TOTAL_SPACE_GB
from dba_segments
where segment_type like 'TABLE%'
group by owner) t,
(select owner, sum(NUM_ROWS*AVG_ROW_LEN)/(1024*1024*1024) TOTAL_SPACE_USED_GB
from dba_tables
group by owner) u
where
t.owner=u.owner
order by owner;
```

Bobby

Comment: @Boby Durrett - Is it possible to check the same in TB i have added extra 1024 but leading to divisor error, any suggestions

Comment: replace 1024*1024*1024 with 1024*1024*1024*1024 to get terabytes.

Comment: @Boby Durrett  - Thanks , but new requirement came in 1) per day consumed space by individual schemas 2) round to two decimals , is this possible point 1 and 2 ?

Comment: I recommend that you rewrite your question stating exactly what question you want answered. Please include the exact version of your Oracle database (like 11.2.0.4) and what software you have licensed. I.e. Is it Enterprise Edition and do you have the Diagnostics and Tuning packs available? If you provide that information I will rewrite my answer best I can to fit your question.